# Automatic decimal places in textbox center of six digits in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to show comma sign center of six digits and have length of textbox 7. for example "123,456" like this.

Comment: `TextBox1.Text = 123456D.ToString("N0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`? But, what `123456` should represent? Currency? Or is `456` the decimal part? Or you just want to insert a *symbol* in the middle of *something*? Plus, where is `123456` coming from? Is it, originally, a number or a string? You're question is missing many details.

Comment: Use the Validating event.  Decimal.TryParse() to convert the text.  If it is happy then ToString("N0") to replace the user's typed text.  What you do when it is not happy is up to you, ErrorProvider is wise.

Comment: Are you saying that you have six characters which are digits? Perhaps you are looking for the [String.Insert(Int32, String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.insert?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: thats example, if we put any six digits then comma sign place between center of digits.

Answer (score 0):

The MaskedTextBox control would be an easy way to accomplish this.

Replace your TextBox by a MaskedTextBox, and try to set the `Mask` to something like this:

```
MaskedTextBox1.Mask = "##0,000"
```

It should make sure that your trailing zero are always showing.